# Showing the convergence of improper integral.

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Hello I have to show that this improper integral is convergent:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{x^2} dx$$
, but I don't have any starting ideea.
Any tips would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try change of variables, $y = \frac 1 x $ the integral reduces to 
$$\int_{\infty}^1 -e^{-y} dy $$